# XML layouts and a statement from SQLite

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I would like to ask you, how is possible to make layout of my application for data from database. I have a template for statement data from database, but I don't know, how to add to this template some elements (as button, text etc) - the problem is, that after adding for example button to this layout will be this button showed so many times, what is the records in database. Specifically:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/rowId" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip" android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="20dip" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="Id..." />

<TextView android:id="@+id/rowDesc" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Descr..." android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:textSize="12dip" android:layout_below="@+id/rowId"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" andfill_parentor="#ffffff" />

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/delete"
    android:gravity="right" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<Button android:id="@+id/ok" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="40px"
        android:onClick="addItem"
        android:text="Add" />
```

I want that button put on the top and only once and under this button I would like to put the statement of the database... In this time the output of XML layout looks following:

### TEXT1 TEXT2    BUTTON IMG-BUTTON

### TEXT1 TEXT2    BUTTON IMG-BUTTON

### TEXT1 TEXT2    BUTTON IMG-BUTTON

...

And I would like to edit the layout so:

### BUTTON

### TEXT1 TEXT2   IMG-BUTTON

### TEXT1 TEXT2   IMG-BUTTON

### TEXT1 TEXT2   IMG-BUTTON

...

But I don't know, how to edit layout for this purpose... So I will be very glad for every hints, how to do...

Thanks million times!

Comment: You should really start to accept answer in your questions! You'll receive more responses when you do this. People might even give you down-votes to get you to do this. I suggest you start accepting answers on your previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where you add these widgets to. But if you're using `ListView` for example, you should move `ok` button from this layout file to a file with `ListView`.